# How ignore some properties in Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a simple class like this :

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Rowversion column in Db tabale get auto value.when I Inser an user with dapper

```
var result = db.Execute("[dbo].[User_Insert]", user, trans,commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Dapper generate parameter for all property and I get error like this

> Procedure or function User_Insert has too many arguments specified.

How can I ignore Rowversion in Dapper parameter?

My procedure code is:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [In4].[User_Insert] 
       @Id         uniqueidentifier,
       @UserName    nvarchar(4000)= NULL   
AS 
BEGIN
   insert into [In4].[Users] ([Id], [UserName])
                 VALUES (@Id, @UserName) 
End
```

Comment: @user2864740 I update my question

Comment: @user2864740 user had Id that I Ignored it in my question.I update question

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in an anonymous object with only the properties you want.

```
var result = db.Execute("[dbo].[User_Insert]", new { user.Id, user.UserName }, trans, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Alternatively, you could use the [Dapper Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib) extensions and create a mapping class, which allows you to ignore specific properties.

Comment: How can I create mapping class for  Dapper Contrib?

Comment: You can add the `[Computed]` attribute from Dapper.Contrib to any properties you want to ignore. I'm not sure if this is only taken into account when using the Dapper.Contrib extension methods though.

Comment: Yes, that only works for Dapper.Contrib extension methods. I am having the same issue as @M.Azad . Any ideas?